# Flour/Instant Dry Yeast Ratio in Thin Pizza Dough

Tags: baking, pizza, yeast

I researched this question before asking, but I could not find a clear information. I'm sorry if I missed it.

I want to make pizza from a leavened dough. I will use instant dry yeast. There are lots of pizza recipes. Is there a ratio for flour / yeast when making pizza dough? Of course, this will vary according to the type of flour. We can talk about bread flour.For example, X grams of instant yeast is used for each cup of flour.

Some sources say that you can use instant yeast up to 0.5% of the amount of flour. Can we make such a generalization?

Comment: There are many styles of pizza.  Some are thick crusted and would require more yeast, some are thin.  Which style are you interested in making?  Neapolitan?  Sicilian?  Chicago-style pan pizza?

Comment: @moscafj Classic thin pizza. I do not have detail about pizza types

Comment: If you want a consistent recipe, *weigh* the flour, don't measure it by using cups, whose contents can vary significantly from one time to the next.

Answer (score 2):

Pizza dough is basically a bread.  So, like other bread formulas, can be developed and expressed using a bakers percentage.  For a Napolitan pizza most pizzaiolos use .1 to .5 percent yeast.  This is the percentage as compared to the total amount of flour (usually tipo "OO" for this style).  So, your initial research is a good starting point.  You will have to adjust for local conditions (and ingredients) from there. [This might also help you.](https://www.pizzatoday.com/departments/in-the-kitchen/knead-to-know-neapolitan-pizza-dough/) He makes use of fresh yeast, so that is likely why his percentage is on the lower end.

Comment: I agree that there is a range. It is even wider than what you state - I have seen recipes with up to 2% dry yeast. Yes, I know that the high numbers are frowned upon in some popular sources, but they are nevertheless widespread. So I would say that anything between 0.1% and 2% is normal.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't make such a generalization. There are many possible ratios, and they interact with the ratio of the other ingredients and with the process used to make the pizza. That's exactly why have recipes: each recipe is a combination of ratios and process that work well together.

If you want to make a pizza, your chances for success are highest if you follow a recipe literally, without trying to second-guess it.